# Ugly indention with Sinatra ERB partials

Tags: ruby, sinatra, partial-views, erb

I have a problem in Sinatra with ERB templating engine. Partials are rendered with wrong indention.

There is no custom helpers, or [sinatra-partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial) gem, just vanilla Sinatra. Also have 'sinatra-contrib' installed, if it makes any difference.

Editor is Sublime Text, and all files use spaces for indention. Sublime Text has `ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save` setting enabled (I tried to disable it, but it gives no difference).

**Views structure**

```
views
   |- layouts
       |- application.erb
   |- main
       |- index.erb
   |- partials
       |- header.erb
```

**layouts/application.erb**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main/index.erb**

```
<article>
  <%= erb :'partials/header', layout: false %>
</article>
```

**partials/header.erb**

```
<header>
  <h1>Newsletter</h1>
</header>
```

Renders HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <article>

  <header>
  <h1>Newsletter</h1>
</header>

</article>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does it matter? Does the page look wrong? Is the HTML malformed?

Comment: @TomLord Everything works as expected, except indention is not pretty. I guess I'll have to live with that

Comment: Does it even matter that the indentation isn't pretty? When you inspect anything in the browser, it auto-prettifies the HTML whitespace for you regardless.

Comment: I've had similar problems with ERB in the past and found no way to properly fix it, [as have others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53167613/335847).

Comment: @TomLord, maybe i'm missing something, but my browsers don't auto-pretiffy anything

Comment: @icherevkov Right click --> Inspect. Don't "view page source".

Comment: @TomLord yes, thanks. I never payed attention inspector actually prettifies html. although, my inner perfectionist is not satisfied